# WebBrowser control HTMLDocument automate selecting option drop-down

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to automate in a WinForm using a WebBrowser control to navigate and pull report info from a website. You can enter values in textboxes and invoke the click events for buttons and links, but I have not figured out how select a option drop-down .... in a automated way. Anybody recommend how to select a item from a drop-down, given this html example:

```
<SELECT id="term_id" size="1" name="p_term_in"><option value="">Select Another Term<option value="201050">Summer 2010<option value="201010">Spring 2010<option value="200980">Fall 2009</SELECT>
```

For others that can learn from entering values to textboxes and invoking click events here's how you do it:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("<HTML ELEMENT NAME>").SetAttribute("value", "THE NAME");
```

Invoke button or hyperlink click:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("<BUTTON>").InvokeMember("click");
```

So I've solved entering values and invoking click, but I have not solved selecting a drop-down value.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you have the following select in the HTML:

```
<select id="term_id" size="1" name="p_term_in">
    <option value="">Select Another Term
    <option value="201050">Summer 2010
    <option value="201010">Spring 2010
    <option value="200980">Fall 2009
</select>
```

This should allow you to preselect the third value:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("term_id").SetAttribute("value", "201010");
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not work as the `select` element does not have a `value` attribute. Just tested it ...

Answer (score 6):

```
var select = webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("ddlProyectos");

mshtml.HTMLSelectElement cbProyectos = select.DomElement as mshtml.HTMLSelectElement;

var total = cbProyectos.length;
for (var i= 0; i < total; i++)
{
    cbProyectos.selectedIndex = i;
    if (cbProyectos.value.Contains("13963"))
    {
        break;
    }

}
//cbProyectos.selectedIndex = 4;
select.InvokeMember("onchange");

select.Children[4].SetAttribute("selected", "selected");

var theElementCollection = webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select");
foreach (HtmlElement el in theElementCollection)
{
    if (el.GetAttribute("value").Equals("13963"))
    {
        el.SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
        //el.InvokeMember("click");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion works in that the option gets selected correctly (I can see it selected). However, the script associated with the option doesn't seem to run. When I manually selected this option afterwards, the script runs fine. Do you have any idea why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

You will have to select the `selected` attribute on the option you want.

Given:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

The following would selct the third option:

```
webBrowser1.Document
           .GetElementById("")
           .Children.GetElementsByName("option")[2]
           .SetAttribute("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 4):

try this:

add reference to microsoft.mshtml in project --> add reference...

```
    Dim cboTemp As mshtml.HTMLSelectElement
    cboTemp = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("myselect").DomElement
    cbotemp.selectedindex = 2
```

having the variable cbotemp set to a select element gives you greater access to the control :)

Answer (score 3):

```
HtmlElement hField = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ID");  
hField.SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "2");
```

select by **index** (*zero based*) not the **value**....

Answer (score 3):

I'm answering on this post after five years, for the people who are searching a solution of this problem.

If you just need to submit/post a value for the dropdown then this line is sufficient:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("term_id").SetAttribute("value", "200980");
```

But if you really need to select an underlying OPTION, then:

```
HtmlElement selectDom = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("term_id");
foreach (HtmlElement option in selectDom.GetElementsByTagName("option"))
{
    if (option.GetAttribute("value") == "200980")
    {
        var dom = option.DomElement as dynamic;
        dom.selected = true;
        // selectDom.InvokeMember("onChange"); // if you need this too
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("term_id").SetAttribute("value",yourText);
```