# How do I change a dropdown box in a webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, webbrowser-control

So I have a listbox I want to change, that looks like this:

[image]

How do I change the July value? I need this to be 100% automated and change it to January. I made a lot of accounts on various websites and need to change them all back to the same birthdate. Yes, I'm aware I'll have to find the ID of it, etc.

Comment: What technology?  ASP.NET, MVC?  What kind of DD, asp.net, DevExpress, telerik?

Comment: My program is in C#. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: C# is a programming language.  You tagged this question "website". Controls like DropDownMenu differ depending on the type of web technology you are using.  The web technology is what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't know... I'm using a WebBrowser control. I untagged website, I guess that's confusing.

Comment: You want to automate a browser? What about Selenium?

Comment: No, in C#, I want to change the value of a DropDown box. For a TextBox I would just use     webBrowser.GetElementById("ID_NAME").InternalText = "TEXT";, but that doesn't work with dropdowns.

Comment: Your missing the document reference.  webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("dropdownID")

Comment: @Jesse I've got my money on a Dating WebSite robot...

Comment: @Jessie I have a lot of gmail accounts from earlier (all of them forward to my main email, and I use them on sites such as prizerebel where you get lots of spam, and gmail has the BEST spam filter ever), and I am having trouble remembering their passwords. In order to reset it, I have to know the DoB, and I just used random ones.

Comment: Also, I can't create accounts ANYWHERE with this. Why? Capychya. Just saying.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [WebBrowser control HTMLDocument automate selecting option drop-down](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2351537/3744182), agree?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

View the HTML of the website and identify the **id** and **values** of the dropdownlist, for example:

```
<select id="bdayMonthId" size="1" name="bdayMonth">
    <option value="">Month</>
    <option value="Jan">January</>
    <option value="Feb">February</>
    <option value="Mar">March</>
</select>
```

To pre-select the dropdownlist value in the WebBrowser control use this Winform code:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("bdayMonthId").SetAttribute("value", "Feb");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about your question. If you just want to alter an element in the HTML, [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/495455/jeremy-thompson)'s answer is the best, and simplest, way to go. If you wanted to call the document's javascript, this should work:

Let's assume that the webbrowser's document contains the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Invoke Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="testdiv">Waiting...</div>
        <script>
            function changeDate(date) {
                var x=document.getElementById("testdiv");
                x.innerHTML = date;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

To invoke the webbrowser document's javascript method, you can use something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object o = webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("changeDate('june')");
}
```

No System.Web, ASP, ScriptManagers or Interop are needed. All the tools you need to control webbrowser and document objects and events come with the webbrowser control.