# How can I change the value of a tool comboBox in a DataGrid in a webBrowser tool on the site by code?

Tags: c#, datagrid, combobox

My brothers, I make a program using c # 2010 to lift the data to a Web site by using the tool is lifted webBrowser and data into a tool DataGrid on the site, but one of the pillars DataGrid contains a The comboBox where the software will fill in the cells of the DataGrid but The comboBox I select values ​​manually 
  The question / How can I change the value of a tool comboBox in a DataGrid in a webBrowser tool on the site by code?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking. Do you want to know how to set the values of the combobox in the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this correct, you are using a `WebBrowser` control to display a webpage and want to fill data into a combobox / dropdown. If so, look at this question: [How do I change a dropdown box in a webbrowser control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224535/how-do-i-change-a-dropdown-box-in-a-webbrowser-control).

Answer (score 0):

Very sorry to ask the question is wrong but this Google translation So please understand my position and helped me solve my problem and thank you
I'm use this code 
 webBrowser1.Document.Window.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_DynamicGrid_ctl" + a + "_ctl" + tb3).SetAttribute("value", "1000");