# How Can I Select a Drop Down Option on a Webpage?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

How could I go about selecting an option from a drop down menu on a web page? I have the following:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("wpbdp-field-2");
    foreach (HtmlElement HtmlElement1 in webBrowser1.Document.Body.All)
    {
        if (HtmlElement1.GetAttribute("value") == "Continue")
        {
            HtmlElement1.InvokeMember("click");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

"Wpbdp-field-2" is the drop down menu. How could I change the default box, which is "yes" in this case, to "no" which is the second drop down option?

I apologize if this isn't clear.

Comment: Is this a Windows Forms application, WPF, or what? Is this the standard "Web Browser Control"? Also, ask yourself how you would do this with JavaScript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12226520/3419300