# Select Item of webbrowser dropdown list C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I want select item from dropdown list in winforms C# app. 
I have:

```
<select name ="petbet">
<option value="1">Speedy</option>
<option value="2">Snuffles</option>
<option value="3">Sneak</option>
<option value="4">Snow</option>
<option value="5">Slowww</option>
```

I try:

```
var test = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select").Count;
        webBrowser2.Document.Forms[0].SetAttribute("value", "3");
```

I want select sneak, but don't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebBrowser control HTMLDocument automate selecting option drop-down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351537/webbrowser-control-htmldocument-automate-selecting-option-drop-down)

Comment: What if you `InvokeMember('click')` on the option element? Also, setting the value to 3 on `webBrowser2.Document.Forms[0]` makes no sense. You want to find the option element as a child of petbet.